# Rails Association Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't seem to be understanding this "association" business in rails fully...hoping someone can help.

**Model One**

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

**Model Two**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

When I go to find all "products" that are currently supported and then associate there vendor names...I'm not getting the correct results:

```
Product.where("is_supported = true").joins(:vendor)
```

The resulting query is:

```
 SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `vendors` ON `vendors`.`id` = `products`.`vendor_id` WHERE (is_supported = true)
```

The issue is SELECT products.* instead of SELECT *

What am I missing to get the vendor table to join its own fields with the products table?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are making a JOIN and now you are working with 2 tables at same time. Then , rails makes a specific query.

Answer (score 0):

An initial comment: When using Ruby on Rails (or any other SQL hiding framework) one should not worry (too much) about the underlying SQL queries. They are generated as needed (and might be 'sub-optimal')

To answer your question: 'How can I get the vendor information from a product object' (or that is at least how I read it)

The `belongs_to`, `has_many` and other associations add an attribute to the implementing class (in your case the `Product` and `Vendor` classes). You can use this attribute to get the information of the associated object.

```
p = getSomeProduct(...)
v = p.vendor
vendorName = p.vendor.name # or use v.name of course
```

This code will probably (can't check to be sure sure ATM) generate and execute multiple SQL queries. This is the price to pay to use a framework that hides SQL from the developer.

Please read the [guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more information about associations in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: The example definitely helped!